# How to fix code formatting issues if the edit includes spaces only and does not include 6 characters?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I came across a question which had a code snippet. Unfortunately, first line of the code snippet was not aligned properly, and the second line was blank; so it escaped Stack Overflow's code highlighting, like this:

int main() {

```
    return 0;

}
```

I thought it would be a good idea to edit the question so the first line is also clearly included in the snippet, i.e. change question's source from this:

```
Some question.

int main() {

        return 0;

    }
```

to this:

```
Some question.

    int main() {

        return 0;

    }
```

I consider this edit minor, but objective and important for readability. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow told me that "edits should be at least 6 characters long". I've tried removing extra lines and trailing spaces to make it 6 characters change, not 4, but without luck. I assume that Stack Overflow counts non-space characters only.

I'm wondering how to suggest such changes?

I've read [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/767632) to "When should I make edits to code?" question and it says that adding code blocks around code is in the "Do" list, so I'm assuming "adding *some* code in code blocks" is also in the "Do" list.

Comment: As an aside, if there's an issue with their formatting, there is ***more than likely*** six characters' worth of improvement with their question.